MacOS Sequoia and .NET MAUI
I updated OS to MacOS Sequoia, also XCode updated to version 16.0.
After that my .NET MAUI project stopped being deployed (compilation was ok). And deploy failed with error in the console:

Could not load the framework 'IDEDistribution'

Tried to pair my mac with Visual Studio on Windows computer, and get the same error upon attempt to deploy binary to the actual device.
Also, there are no available simulators are being displayed on Visual Studio for Mac, and Visual Studio on paired Windows computer.
How can I fix that?

The reason is that XCode 16.0 does not work with .NET MAUI. The bonus part is that you can't install XCode 15.4 to MacOS Sequoia. Because it is not compatible with MacOS Sequoia.
To solve this task I did the following steps:

Completely uninstalled XCode 16

Downloaded XCode 16.0 Beta from here: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/


Important note: Download the first beta version, released on June 10, 2024

Click on "View details" and download Xcode_16_beta.xip
https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_16_beta/Xcode_16_beta.xip
After extraction renamed *.app file from Xcode_beta.app to Xcode.app and placed Xcode.app file to Applications folder.

Launched XCode and downloaded simulator runtime (menu: Xcode -> Settings, then open "Components" tab).

In the same settings window in "Account" tab, specified my Apple Id credentials, to setup certificates and provisioning profiles.

Downloaded and installed "Command line tools for XCode 16 beta" released on June 10, 2024




Restarted my Mac computer.

Paired it from Windows computer.


Now build and deploy works, and simulators are available for selection.
Special thanks to Brian McCarty for his valuable comment on GitHub discussions.
