error : clang++ exited with code 1 error in MAUI app VS code
I'm using VS code for MAUI application. VS code Version: 1.93.1 .
Xcode Version 16.0. There is no issue with the code. Facing iOS SDK issues.
I'm facing the below error.
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8030/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1641,3): error : clang++ exited with code 1: [/Users/#####/Documents/###-dfp-###-mobile-maui/src/####/###.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8030/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1641,3): error : ld: in /Users/####/Documents/####-dfp-####-mobile-maui/src/####/obj/Debug/net8.0-ios/iossimulator-arm64/linker-cache/AppCenterCrashes.a(MSACErrorReport.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/####/Documents/####-dfp-####-mobile-maui/src/####/obj/Debug/net8.0-ios/iossimulator-arm64/linker-cache/AppCenterCrashes.a' [/Users/####/Documents/####-dfp-####-mobile-maui/src/####/####.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8030/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1641,3): error : clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) [/Users/####/Documents/####-dfp-####-mobile-maui/src/####/####.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Xcode 16 is currently not supported yet. Also see: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/24819 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79020417/macos-sequoia-and-net-maui

@GeraldVersluis I have uninstalled Xcode 16 and installed Xcode 16.1 Beta 2 version. Still I'm facing the same issue

@GeraldVersluis Xcode16-Beta version also installed and tried. Same errors getting

No version of Xcode 16 is officially supported. Some people managed to make it work, but you'll have the best experience currently with Xcode 15.4

@GeraldVersluis Xcode 15.4 is not supporting for the current Mac OS

That is correct, that is the problem which is mentioned in the links I posted initially. Please read the linked blog post in those links for something you can try if you don't want to reformat your machine.

Are you building on Apple silicon (M1) and reference a dependency that doesn't support iossimulator-arm64? This might help:
<PropertyGroup>
  <RuntimeIdentifier>iossimulator-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>

See alo https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/744

I'm not building on on Apple silicon (M1)

This is not the problem/solution. Its that Xcode 16 is not officially supported right now as pointed out in the comments.

Check please this.
Your problem is expected here
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/24819
